# Order of operations between timewindow to sink pipeline

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Suppose I have a flink pipeline as such:
`kafka_source -> maps/filters/keyBy/timewindow(1 minute) -> sinkCassandra`

By the time the grouped messages hit the `sinkCassandra` operation, am I guaranteed that no other slots won't also concurrently run the `maps/filters/keyBy/timewindow(1 minute)` part of the pipeline?

Or is it possible to have some other slot run the middle pipeline while another set is running the sinkCassandra operation?

EDIT ( Added more requirements based on comment conversation ):

What I'm trying to do is effectively do a lookup based on flink data key from the datastore, and do an update and flush the updated data back.

The reason why I'm dodging using `kafka_source -> maps/filters -> keyBy/TimeWindow/statefulReduce -> sinkCassandra` is because the state can potentially get huge ( 1 day to 7 days where I can place 7 days as the max time bounding ) and I don't necessarily know the time window for each key. This would mean a HUGE state even with rocksdb.

Another potential option that I'm looking at is `kafka_source -> maps/filters -> keyBy/sinkCass` where within the custom sink operation, I would first check in some sort of in-memory buffer if I have the key that I want to update. If not, I go ahead and fetch from Cassandra. Every 5 seconds ( or every N seconds ), I would grab whatever's in the buffer and flush into Cassandra. To limit memory, I can do an in-memory least recently used hashmap ( I don't necessarily want to flush b/c multiple keys will show up again! )

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have explicitly configured something unusual, each slot will contain one parallel slice of the complete pipeline -- each slot will have a kafka source instance connected to a disjoint subset of the kafka partitions, as well as the maps/filters/keyBy/window, and the cassandra sink.

All of those parallel sub-pipelines (slots) will be running concurrently. Furthermore, within each slot, each of the operators will also be running concurrently. The sink and the middle part of your pipeline are already running concurrently, but they are competing for the resources of the slot that contains them both. You can configure your task managers to have more cores per slot if you are concerned about starvation.

EDiT (responding to add'l info about requirements):

You can safely assume that for any given flink data key, after a keyBy, only one instance of each operator will process events for that key. That principle is fundamental to Flink's design. If I understand correctly what you are contemplating, that's the only guarantee you need.

Comment: what I want to do is do a lookup from the datastore ( memcached/cassandra ), update its value based off of what flink values have based on key, and push the updated value back. This is effectively a state. The reason why I'm dodging the keyed state is b/c these keys have a potential huge time bound ( think between 1 day to 7 days ). And we don't know what the time bounding is for each key so I cannot simply use a keyBy/timeWindow/KeyedReduce.

Comment: What I'm thinking is having a ``kafka_source -> maps/filters -> keyBy_and_sink``. That sink would do a lookup the values from these stores IF the key doesn't exist for data in some sort of temporary buffer, else I'd update the temporary buffer. Every 5 seconds or every time I hit some key count buffer, I "flush" this buffer by updating memcached or cassandra and empty my buffer. ( This memcached/cassandra is effectively used from our other service as a read only data store...flink will be the one populating this )

Comment: This way, I *don't* think I'll run into data race issues since I do a keyBy per each key and each key will ( every now and then ) do a lookup from the datastores, and flush

Comment: ``Furthermore, within each slot, each of the operators will also be running concurrently``
For each slot, yeah, I would have each slot have operators and each operators running concurrently BUT I don't think I'll have multiple instances of those operators  per slot running at the same time...which means I can do a safe lookup on that keyedStream sink and datastore flush every now and then

Comment: Could you please edit your question to contain these clarifications? That will help others benefit from this.